# Hybris cs-cockpit currency position

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, cs-cockpit

my cscockpit is displaying let says"125.00PHP" in price value.
Is there any config parameter or impex to change to "PHP125.00"?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the widget corresponding to this layout.

For the same, you need to extend `de.hybris.platform.cscockpit.widgets.renderers.impl.BasketTotalsWidgetRenderer`and override `renderOrderDetail` method of `AbstractOrderTotalsWidgetRenderer`

You need to change the below code block as per your requirement

```
NumberFormat currencyInstance = (NumberFormat) getSessionService()
                    .executeInLocalView(
                            new SessionExecutionBody(cartCurrencyModel) {
                                public Object execute() {
                                    AbstractOrderTotalsWidgetRenderer.this
                                            .getCommonI18NService()
                                            .setCurrentCurrency(
                                                    this.val$cartCurrencyModel);
                                    return AbstractOrderTotalsWidgetRenderer.this
                                            .getFormatFactory()
                                            .createCurrencyFormat();
                                }
                            });
```